# Family tree of Prishadhra?

Tags: mahabharata, manu, family

What is family tree of Prishadhra?what is name of child of Prishadhra ? Do child of prishadhra is shudra or Kshatriya?

Answer (score 2):

```
What is family tree of Prishadhra?
```

According to Scriptures, **Prishadhra was the son of Vaivasvata Manu.**
I am quoting from [Agni Purana, Chapter 273](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-agni-purana/d/doc1083502.html).

> 5-6. Vaivasvata Manu had eight sons best of all but not equal to him—Ikṣvāku, Nābhāga, Dhṛṣṭa, Śaryāti, Nariṣyanta, Prāṃsu, Karuṣa and Pṛṣadhra. They were of great prowess and lived in Ayodhyā.

Accidentally, he killed a cow, so his **preceptor cursed him to become Shudra**

> 18. Prṣadhra became a śūdra on account of killing the cow of his preceptor.

Detailed story of Prishadhra killing cow is mentioned in [Shiva Purana - Section 5 - Umā-Saṃhitā, Chapter 36](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226596.html).

> 53. Pṛṣadhra, a son of Manu was made the keeper of cows by his preceptor. During the nights, observing the posture of heroes, he diligently looked after the cows.

> 54. Once a tiger entered the cowshed to attack the cows. On hearing the shrieks of the cows he woke up. Strong that he was he seized a sword to kill it and started.

> 55. On seeing the lord armed with a sword the frightened tiger slipped away. Not knowing it and mistaking a reddish brown cow as the tiger he hit it with his sword on its head.

> 56. Due to rain and gust of wind in the night he was deluded. Thinking, that the tiger had been killed he returned to his place.

> 57. When the night dawned into day he got up and went there. He saw only the cow killed and not the tiger. He felt dejected.

> 58. **On hearing about the incident and realising that he had committed a sin unconsciously and not wilfully, the preceptor cursed him—“Become a Śūdra, not a Kṣatriya.”**

> 59. On being cursed by his preceptor, the family priest out of anger, Pṛṣadhra started from there and went to the great forest.

> 60. Dejected by sufferings he became detached and practised Yoga. He burnt himself in conflagration and attained the greatest goal.

Lastly, Prishadhra took the wow of celibacy as it is mentioned in [Srimad Bhagavatam - Canto 9 - Chapter 2](http://www.srimadbhagavatam.org/canto9/chapter2.html#Text_10)

> 10. The hero thus being cursed by his guru, accepted the words with folded hands and took the vow of celibacy the way the sages want it.